# Passing in filename from command line to read file content

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, fopen, argv, argc

I have a function `./transform` that needs to take in two command line arguments for an input and output file.

Like so: `./transform "inputfile" "outputfile"`

I am then trying to read the file using `fopen` to store each character in the file into a character array `char token[1024]`. The total number of characters in the input file will always be <= 1024.

I am receiving errors about `fopen` not having the right amount of arguments. Here is pseudo-code of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
void main(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){
    char token[1024];
    token = fopen(&inputFile, "r");
}
```

Yes, I am aware I am trying to assign a FILE value to a Char value... I wrote it this way to show that I want each character from the inputFile stored in the character  array. I am unsure how to do so properly. After executing the program's code (converting hex and int values from file to ASCII), I need to save the converted ASCII text into the user-defined output file.

Comment: The main function has 2 arguments, int argc - the number of arguments, and char* argv[] - a string array of the arguments passed in. It can't take a FILE as a cmdline argument.

Comment: Also, fopen takes in a string as the first argument, not a file.

Comment: @Matt, I cannot use strings, would passing in character arrays like so work? main(char inputFile[], char outputFile][]){}

Comment: As you mentioned, fopen returns a file pointer, not a string, and c wont let you cast that automatically. You need to assign the output to a var of type FILE, then read that into your string.

Comment: When I say string, I'm referring to a null terminated char array. If you want to use commandline args, you need to use the argc/argv arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the code you tried, firstly here

```
void main(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile){ }
```

you are trying to change prototype of `main()` which is not correct. According to  [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) **Section 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**, either it should be

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

So make it like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /*some_code */
}
```

Next, to open a file using `fopen()` from command line, this

```
token = fopen(&inputFile, "r");
```

is completely wrong as `fopen()` returns argument of `FILE*` not `char*` & argument you provided to `fopen()` also wrong. Read then manual page of [fopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) ,it says

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

Sample code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if( argc!= 3 ) { /*if user input is not correct, inform user */
     printf("./transform inputfile outputfile \n");
     return 0;
  }
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r); 
  if(fp == NULL) {
     /* error handling */
     return 0;
  }
  /* do_stuff_with_fp */  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I really appreciate the help and fixing some of the other issues I had!

Comment: @jasonsogan WC !!